# SQL: Join everything with everything

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `rabatt` database (sales discount) and I want an SQL statement that returns:

```
   fnrvon     fnran      prozent
----------- ----------- -----------
101             102        5.25
101             103        15.75
101             104        0.00
101             105        0.00
101             106        0.00
101             107        0.00
102             101        5.50
102             103        10.50
102             104        0.00
102             105        0.00
102             106        0.00
102             107        0.00
........
```

I tried

```
select * from rabatt r1 cross join rabatt r2;
```

and

```
select distinct r1.fnrvon, r2.fnran 
    from rabatt r1 
    cross join rabatt r2
    where r1.fnrvon != r2.fnran
    order by r1.fnrvon;
```

but somehow it doesn't return the above result. Any ideas?

Example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae116)

Comment: what does the data look like in your tables ??

Comment: The query you posted should give you the result. Here is the alternate query. 

`SELECT DISTINCT R1.FNRVON, R1.FNRAN, R1.PROZENT
FROM RABATT R1, RABATT R2 WHERE R1.FNRVON <> R2.FNRAN
ORDER BY R1.FNRVON;`

What kind of result do you want?

Comment: The fnran column doesn't have any row with value 104 and 105. So it wont come in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, provided you can acces the `firma` table:

```
SELECT f1.fnr AS 'from', f2.fnr AS 'to', COALESCE(r.prozent, 0)
FROM firma f1
CROSS JOIN firma f2
LEFT JOIN rabatt r ON r.fnrvon = f1.fnr AND r.fnran = f2.fnr
WHERE f1.fnr != f2.fnr
ORDER BY f1.fnr, f2.fnr;
```

if you, for some reason can't, you can replace `firma` with a subquery:

```
SELECT fnrvon FROM rabatt UNION SELECT fnran FROM rabatt;
```

Comment: Wow! Great thanks very much! I knew it had to do with cross join! Thank you!